# Robuist image uploader/resizer API?

Tags: image, api, image-processing

Do you know a stable image hosting and resizing API? There are many new ones in this area, but they seem to be more side projects than a robust service with a business model that ensures continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://transloadit.com/ seems to be the solution!

Answer (score 0):

There are several serious contenders in this space now but I'd like to cover one: [ImageServe](https://imgserve.io) (Disclaimer: I'm involved with it)

What you should be looking at is a service which offers the complete pipeline, starting from a place to host your images, to real-time image processing API to caching and delivery through image CDN. This would remove any burden from you to build your image delivery pipeline. Besides ImageServe, there are others like Cloudinary but they've a skewed pricing model since often times you don't know how many different processing queries you may end up applying etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Imagizer Engine - http://imagizer.com
It has a URL based API that can take URL parameters like &width= and &height= that allows you to resize any image has a public URL.

Here is the link to API: http://demo.nventify.com/doc/

(disclaimer: I am involved with this Co.)